# Checksum of seven-digit number input through keyboard

Tags: python

I am trying to get the checksum of a seven-digit number input through the keyboard. The input would be restricted to exactly 7 digits. I already have this code below but can't get to restrict it to only 7 digits.

```py
n = int(input("Enter number")) 
total = 0 

while n > 0: 
    newNum = n % 10
    total = total + newNum 
    n = n // 10 

print(total)
```

If I enter 4 digits, the code will still run. I just want to restrict it to only 7 digits.

Comment: make a condition for the input to be not longer than 7 digits?

Comment: get input as string and check `len(n) == 7` - and later convert to integer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of instantly converting the input to an integer, keep it as a string, so you can make a condition for the length of the input.

something like:

```
n = input("Enter number ")
m = int(n)
total = 0

while m > 0 and len(n)==7: 
    newNum = m%10
    total = total + newNum 
    m = m//10

print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the input number as a string, so that you have an easy way to count and sum over the digits:

```py
s = ''

while len(s) != 7:
    s = input("Enter a 7-digit number")

total = sum(int(char) for char in s)    
print(total)
```

Comment: returns error...... TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Hmm, it works for me. Have you perhaps shadowed the `sum()` function by calling a variable `sum`? That's most probably the cause of the error you get. Change the name of that variable, restart your kernel and try again.

Answer (score 1):

```
num = str(input("Enter a seven-digit number: "))
if len(num) !=7:
    print("Please Enter a seven-digit number!")
else:
    sumNum = 0
    m = int(num)
    while m>0:
        newnum = m%10
        sumNum = sumNum + newnum
        m = m//10
    print("The sum of its digits is: ",sumNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the input before turning it into a `int`.
Since strings can be iterated over, like list, their length can be checked in the same way as lists with the `len()` function. as so:

```
if len(n) != 7:
    print("input must be seven digits long")
    n = input("Enter number")
```